# Email from my new vps is marked as spam

Tags: email, email-server, spam, gmail, google

I got a new vps from x10vps (x10hosting) and set up the domain via cloudflare.

This is what the email looks like:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.64.19.240 with SMTP id i16csp357708iee;
        Tue, 9 Oct 2012 01:29:48 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.50.57.130 with SMTP id i2mr908846igq.56.1349771387599;
        Tue, 09 Oct 2012 01:29:47 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <xxx@chvw.de>
Received: from power.SOURCEAPE.COM ([198.91.90.116])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v8si25630942ica.46.2012.10.09.01.29.46
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Tue, 09 Oct 2012 01:29:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of xxx@chvw.de: DNS timeout) client-ip=198.91.90.116;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of xxx@chvw.de: DNS timeout) smtp.mail=xxx@chvw.de
Received: from nk11p03mm-asmtp010.mac.com ([17.158.232.169]:54276)
    by power.SOURCEAPE.COM with esmtp (Exim 4.80)
    (envelope-from <xxx@chvw.de>)
    id 1TLVBD-0004Ig-1Y
    for xxx@chvw.de; Tue, 09 Oct 2012 12:28:43 +0400
```

I then tried to enable SPF and DKIM and got following massage

```
In order to ensure that SPF or DKIM takes effect, you must confirm that this server is an authoritative nameserver for chvw.de. If you need help, contact your hosting provider.

Status: Enabled Warning: cPanel is unable to verify that this server is an authoritative nameserver for chvw.de. [?]
```

and the email header now looks like this:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.50.183.227 with SMTP id ep3csp14506igc;
        Tue, 9 Oct 2012 01:55:23 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.50.40.133 with SMTP id x5mr992934igk.32.1349772923717;
        Tue, 09 Oct 2012 01:55:23 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <xxx@chvw.de>
Received: from power.SOURCEAPE.COM ([198.91.90.116])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ng8si25688859icb.42.2012.10.09.01.55.23
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Tue, 09 Oct 2012 01:55:23 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of xxx@chvw.de: DNS timeout) client-ip=198.91.90.116;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of xxx@chvw.de: DNS timeout) smtp.mail=xxx@chvw.de; dkim=neutral (bad format) header.i=@chvw.de
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=chvw.de; s=default;
    h=Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version; bh=iugsx3Lx0KnqjR7dj3wyQHnJ9pe/z3ntYEVk80k8rx4=;
    b=IrYsCtHdoPubXVOvLqxd7sLE/TyQTS5P3OrEg5SSUSKnQQcQ/fWWyBrmsrgkFSsw6jCmmRWMDR09vH5bQRpFPMA57B7pf8QRKhwXOWFBV+GnVUqICsfRjnNPvhx/lNp5;
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:46539 helo=direct.chvw.de)
    by power.SOURCEAPE.COM with esmtpa (Exim 4.80)
    (envelope-from <xxx@chvw.de>)
    id 1TLVb0-0004dZ-Kd
    for xxx@gmail.com; Tue, 09 Oct 2012 12:55:22 +0400
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the DKIM, but you don't seem to have any SPF records:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig txt chvw.de

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P3-RedHat-9.8.3-4.P3.fc16 <<>> txt chvw.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64092
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;chvw.de.           IN  TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
chvw.de.        10631   IN  SOA bob.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2012092713 10000 2400 604800 3600
```

So when you say you enabled SPF, what exactly did you do?  Getting working SPF records would definitely be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those listings shouldn't be an issue with Spamhaus now. If the user was missing TXT/SPF records in their zone file, they should add the records in their CloudFlare DNS settings (settings->DNS settings).

Answer (score -1):

> "and set up the domain via cloudflare".

that could be your problem. chvw.de's A and NS ips are both blacklisted at spamhaus.

- http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/query/SBL146750
- http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/query/SBL146751
- http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/listings/cloudflare.com